# Почему в данном коде не работает def?

Tags: python

Хочу сделать, чтобы текст показывался с интервалом. Проблема в том, что когда делаешь без функции def, выводится весь текст, а не частями. Функция def почему-то не работает.

```
one = font.render(text1, 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))
two = font.render(text2, 2, (12, 140, 0, 1))
three = font.render(text3, 3, (12, 140, 0, 1))

while True: 
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for click in pygame.event.get():
        if click.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            time.sleep(0.10)
            pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('111.jpg'))
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1020))
            pygame.display.set_caption('Внимание!!!')
            messagebox.showerror('аха', ' dd')




    def lol():
        pygame.time.delay(500)
        screen.blit(one, (0, 50))
        lol()
    
    def kek():
        pygame.time.delay(700)
        screen.blit(two, (0, 100))
        kek()

    def chebyrek():
        pygame.time.delay(900)
        screen.blit(three, (0, 150))
        chebyrek()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: функции def нужно разместить в начале кода.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать, но одна проблема тут точно есть - одинаковое название переменных `txt1`-`txt3` и функций.

Comment: @VasilijsLaskovskis, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы screen.blit(txt1, (0, 50)), screen.blit(txt2, (0, 100)), screen.blit(txt3, (0, 150)) было внутри функции while. Как так сделать?

Comment: NikeTos, @VasilijsLaskovskis, не надо называть их "функции def ", пожалуйста.  Это просто "функции".
И кроме того, что переменные и функции одинаково называются, так я ещё и вызова функций не вижу.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, смотрите, я хочу, чтобы этот текст выводился по очереди ( с интервалом). Без функции def получается так, что выводится весь текст. С функцией def, я думаю, должно было всё получиться, но она не работает

Comment: @Сергей  прошу прощения , да это просто функции.

Comment: @NikeTos вы повторили то же самое, что и в вопросе. Мне понятней не стало. "выводится весь текст, а не частями" - объясните, что имеется ввиду.

Comment: @Сергей, изменил названия. Функция всё равно не работает

Comment: Все очень просто - нужно взять учебник по питону и читать главу о функциях до понимания. И ещё следить за отступами в коде.

Comment: Ну а "функция все равно не работает" - ну так все ее все еще не вызываете (кроме вызова самой себя, что подвесит вашу программу, как только вызовете). Пробуйте словами описать, что вы хотите, чтоб ваша программа делала

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA,  я хочу разделить эти тексты между собой, чтобы они выводились по очереди. Если их не разделить , то выводится весь текст.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, а как её правильно вызвать?

Comment: Я все еще не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать, потому не знаю. Вы твердите одно и то же, а я вам повторяю, что нужно попытаться описать задачу другими словами, как-то подробней. То что вы повторяете мне не помогает понять.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA я хочу, чтобы текст выводился с интервалом: через 5 секунд после запуска выводится первый текст, через 7 второй, через 9 третий и тд. Возможно, это можно сделать как-то по-другому, но я не знаю как. Я не знаю как это объяснить другими словами.

Comment: Вы не понимаете, что вы делаете. Совсем. Вы функции вызываете в теле самой функции. Откройте учебник и прочитайте, как функции надо определять и как вызывать. Я закончил на этом.

Comment: @Сергей, да, спасибо, не заметил. Функция заработала, но нужного результата всё равно не добился: текст вызывается разом, а не по очереди

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно отображать текст скажем с 5 по 7 секунду, то нужно в цикле проверять, что сейчас от запуска прошло больше 5 и меньше 7 секунд и только в этом случае отображать текст:

```
one = font.render(text1, 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))
while True: 
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for click in pygame.event.get():
        if click.type == pygame.QUIT:
            ...

    if 5000 < pygame.time.get_ticks() < 7000:
        screen.blit(one, (0, 50))
    
    if 7000 < pygame.time.get_ticks() < 10000:
        screen.blit(two, (0, 100))

    ...
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вы правильно меня поняли. Но как сделать, чтобы текст потом не пропадал, а оставался?

Comment: Чтоб не пропадал, уберите проверку на максимальное значение, т.е. оставьте `if 5000 < pygame.time.get_ticks():`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.